# Calculate the rank of each index in a vector

Tags: r, rank

I'd like to calculate the rank of each index within a vector, e.g:

```
x <- c(0.82324952352792, 0.11953364405781, 0.588659686036408, 0.41683742380701, 
       0.11452184105292, 0.438547774450853, 0.586471405345947, 0.943002870306373, 
       0.28184655145742, 0.722095313714817)

calcRank <- function(x){
  sorted <- x[order(x)]
  ranks <- sapply(x, function(x) which(sorted==x))
  return(ranks)
}

calcRank(x)

> calcRank(x)
 [1]  9  2  7  4  1  5  6 10  3  8
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just:

```
rank(x)     # ..... ?

# [1]  9  2  7  4  1  5  6 10  3  8
```

Answer (score 6):

`match` is what you want:

```
match(x, sort(x))
```