# How can I `seq_along` the levels of a factor in R?

Tags: r

Let's say I have this factor

```
x <- factor(c("b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), levels = c("a", "b"))
```

I would like to get this vector from the factor

```
someOperation(x)
# c(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)
```

This doesn't work:

```
order(x)
# c(3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
```

Comment: if `x = c("b", "b", "a", "a", "a") ` and `order(x) = c(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)` then you'll have `x[order(x)] =c("a","a","b","b","a")`, is it what you want? I guess not, otherwise I guess you cannot do so.

Comment: @KevinCazelles no, I just want to get a vector with `c(4, 5, 1, 2, 3)` from  `x`

Comment: `rank(x, ties = 'first')`

Comment: I see you are looking for a function like `sort` that returns the order!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the rank of each index in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002920/calculate-the-rank-of-each-index-in-a-vector)

Comment: @alistaire that's exactly what I needed 

Comment: @alistaire - given a lack of a clear dup, and the specific wording of this question, I reckon you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rank` has an important `ties.method` parameter that can be set to `"first"` to gives the ascending indices like you want:

```r
x <- factor(c("b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), levels = c("a", "b"))

rank(x, ties = 'first')
#> [1] 4 5 1 2 3
```

An equivalent is calling `order` twice:

```r
order(order(x))
#> [1] 4 5 1 2 3
```